# With mouse click zoom chart as popup fullscreen (highcharts)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I have dynamically create charts on div class col-sm 4 which append on #container div, and now I am trying to zoom highchart as fullscreen when I click on it. Like is it on this fiddle below text. I done something similar but have no idea why is not working,Can someone help me pls ?

In my example when i click on chart everything disappears

I would like to have zoom method like is it from this example http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/chart/events-container/

My example: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rZjJbq

chart.blade.php

```
@extends('index.app')

@section('main')
        <style type="text/css">


.col-sm-4 {
   margin-bottom: 20px;
    min-width: 300px;
    max-width: 800px;
    height: 300px;
    margin: 1em auto;
}

  .modal{
        position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);

}
.modal .col-sm-4 {
    height: 90%;
    width: 90%;
    max-width: none;
}

        </style>

<h2 class="text-center" >{{$user->first_name}} Charts </h2>



<div id="main2">
   <div id="col-sm-4" id="col-sm-4"></div>
</div>

 <script type="text/javascript">

$.getJSON( "http://localhost:8000/api/devices", function( res) {


var result = [];
var namesDev = new Array();
console.log(res);

$.each(res, function(c) {
  var deviceNames = res[c].clientAllias;
  var clientId = res[c].clientId;
  clientNames.push(namesDev);
  $.each(res[c].clientData, function(g) {
    $.each(data[c].clientData[g], function(key, val) {
      clientId2 = data[c].clientData[g].clientId;
      var cpu = data[c].clientData[g].cpuUsage;
      var time_usages = data[c].clientData[g].timestamp;
      final= [];
      final.push(time_usages, cpu, clientId2);
      result.push(final);
    });
  });
});

result.sort();

console.log('result', result);console.log('result', result);
var mappedClientsAllias = _.map(_.uniqBy(data, "clientAllias"), "clientAllias");
var mappedClients = _.map(_.uniqBy(data, "clientId"), "clientId");

var clients = [];
_.forEach(mappedClients, function(clientId, clientAllias) {
  var tempClient = {
    Allias:mappedClientsAllias[clientAllias],
    name: clientId,
    data: []
  };
  _.forEach(data, function(tempData) {
    if (clientId === tempData.clientId) {
    _.forEach(tempData.clientData, function(clientData) {
      tempClient.data.push(
        [clientData.timestamp, clientData.cpuUsage, clientId]
      );
    })
    }
  });
    clients.push(tempClient);
  });
console.log("clients", clients);




   var a =_.forEach(clients, function(client) {
      $('<div class="col-sm-4">').css('position','relative')
                .appendTo('#container')
               .highcharts('StockChart',{
                     marker: {
    states: {
      enabled: true
    }
  },
  time: {
        timezoneOffset: -2 * 60
   },
  rangeSelector: {
      y: 15,
    buttons: [
      {
        count: 1,
        type: "minute",
        text: "Sec"
      },

    ],
    title: "sat",
    inputEnabled: true,
    _selected: 1

  },

  title: {
    text: client.Allias
  },
  xAxis: {
    title: {
      enabled: true,
      text: "Processor unit USAGE"
    },
    type: "datetime",
    dateTimeLabelFormats: {
      second: "%H:%M:%S",
      minute: "%H:%M",
      hour: "%H:%M",
      day: "%e. %b"
    }
  },

  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      marker: {
        enabled: false,

      }
    }
  },

  series: [
    {
      name: "Process unit USAGE",
      data: client.data.sort()
    }
  ],

  chart: {
    renderTo: "main"
  },

events: {


    }

                });
           })

 });

$('#main').bind('mousedown', function () {
        $(this).toggleClass('modal');
        $('#main', this).highcharts().reflow();
    });

</script>




 @endsection
```

app.php.blade.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>

     <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- CSRF Token -->
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
    <title>Master thesis application</title>

   <!-- Jquery --> 


  <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">

      <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.15.0/lodash.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/examples/jumbotron-narrow/">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css">

<!-- Import css file-->

<link href="{{asset('css/app.css')}}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>


 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
<!-- Highcharts for normal chart


<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/series-label.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>

-->

<!-- Highcharts for normal tockSchart -->


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/exporting.js"></script>


  </head>
<script type="text/javascript">

</script>
  <body>
     @include('file.hed')

   @include('file.bar')

    <div class="container ">
     @include('file._info')


    @yield('main')
    </div> <!-- /container -->

 @include('file.down')


  </body>
</html>
<script>
window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};

var navbar = document.getElementById("navbar");
var sticky = navbar.offsetTop;

function myFunction() {
  if (window.pageYOffset >= sticky) {
    navbar.classList.add("sticky")
  } else {
    navbar.classList.remove("sticky");
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: If you clean up the code a bit, you will make it a lot easier to help you.

Comment: hmmm ok i wil do it .Sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to the CSS :

```
.col-sm-4.modal  {
    position: fixed !important;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    display:block;
    max-width: none;
    padding:1%;
}
```

**JS**

```
$(".col-sm-4").bind("mousedown", function() {
  $(this).toggleClass("modal");
  $(this).highcharts().reflow();
});
```

[Pen edited](https://codepen.io/taxman972/pen/LJxBNE)

Comment: Thanks a lot again, but i saw again it only zoom first chart(milos) when i click :(

Comment: @Nenad, you want to zoom on both on the same time or on each chart separately ?

Comment: each chart separately

Comment: @Nenad, I updated the pen, now it's zoom on each chart

Comment: For reference, a different way of doing it, almost working: https://jsfiddle.net/ewolden/jdqsr15m/